# BAML Decompiler / Viewer

Tags: wpf, decompiling, baml

Could anyone recommend a good BAML Decompiler / Viewer besides BAML Viewer plugin for Reflector, which doesn't handle path geometry/data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might like to have another look at the BAML addin for reflector as it's been recently updated by Andrew Smith. Have a look at his at [blog post](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/path-data-prefixes-and-known-colors/) you'll note that he has fixed the issue with path data.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [this one](http://www.codeplex.com/stylesexplorer) by [Cristian Ricciolo Civera](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/ricciolocristian/archive/2008/04/05/styles-explorer-baml-decompiler.aspx).

I did not want to use its ClickOnce installer, but the CodePlex site provides a zip file for download.

I had to place `Ricciolo.StylesExplorer.exe` and `Ricciolo.StylesExplorer.MarkupReflection.dll` into GAC to make it work. I guess that is what the installation does in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

BAML source can be viewed in 
**[ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)**.
Just load your compiled managed code, find and click on the *.baml file you will see the source.

Answer (score 0):

[styles explorer](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/ricciolocristian/archive/2008/04/05/styles-explorer-baml-decompiler.aspx)

Haven't tried it myself yet but worth a try