# In what assembly are the WPF UI BAML files?

Tags: wpf, resources, baml

I've seen them before, but I can't seem to find them.

The .baml files for WPF controls are found under an embedded resource called `???.g.resources` where `???` is the name of the assembly.

I've looked through the resources of the following assemblies:

- PresentationUI
- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- WindowsBase

but they aren't in there.  I could have *swore* they were.

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: The OP means system controls like System.Windows.Button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking in PresentationFramework.Aero.dll, PresentationFramework.Classic.dll, PresentationFramework.Royal.dll or PresentationFramework.Luna.dll? Also you can use a [dedicated baml viewer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117469/baml-decompiler-viewer)

Comment: JustDecompile handles baml easy.

Comment: My exp with JustDecompile has been that its been pretty bloated and buggy. ILSpy works well enough with a baml plugin. I like it for that and I'm kinda a mono hoe. Go Cecil, YA!